# Nifi Broken Pipe ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: apache-nifi

In Nifi, I'm running an ExecuteStreamCommand processor which is calling a python script and passing the flowFile to stdin (Ignore StdIN: False). I get constant errors from the processor even though the python script is executing correctly and is able to read from stdin. Why is this error appearing and how can I debug/suppress it?

```
Failed to write flow file to stdin due to Broken pipe: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

[image]

Pandas is used to read from stdin:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, usecols=schema_map.keys(),
                     nrows=50, dtype=parse_schema(schema_map))
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor and additional logs from `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log`? It appears Java (NiFi) is having trouble writing the flowfile content to STDIN.

Comment: Also please share the part of the python code where you are reading from stdin.

Comment: I checked the nifi-app.log but didn't see anything related to stdin or executeStreamCommand (the log happens to be flooded by periodic S3 access denied errors from a fetchS3 processor). Could it be that the flowFile that can't be written to stdin is an error from an upstream processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error shows up because NiFi failed to persist the flowfile state in order to be able to show it's history.

Does this error still show up when you generate a small test flowfile (reading off a very small csv file)? If it does it could be a case of a large file causing a timeout.

For reference, [this](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ExecuteStreamCommand.java#L627) is the line of code that is raising the exception.

I was able to solve this by ignoring stdin but in your case I guess you could write the data to a file and pass the path instead.